# Filter an array of string and replace a part of the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array with a list of Strings (it's quite long, this is just an example), what I'm trying to do is filter all the strings that start with 'INSERT ALL' and modify the number inside the parentheses by the string ' NULL'

This is the original array:

`let arrSt = [ 'INSERT ALL bmw model 320d (111, bmw)', 'ford focus st d (222, ford)', 'INSERT ALL audi a5 rs (333, audi)', 'opel astra d (444, opel)', ]`

This is the array I'm trying to get:

`[ 'INSERT ALL bmw model 320d (NULL, bmw)', 'ford focus st d (222, ford)', 'INSERT ALL audi a5 rs (NULL, audi)', 'opel astra d (444, opel)', ]`

This is what I do:

`arrSt.filter((items: any) => items.startsWith('INSERT ALL')) .map((item: any) => item.replace(/\(\d+,/g, '(NULL,'))`

When displaying the result in the console, `console.log(arrSt)` returns the original array, nothing has been modified, I've been using .map for a short time, but why doesn't it affect the array?

**UPDATE:**

From an array of string identify the elements that begin with that string. That is to say:

This is the array: `['bmw', 'ferrari']`

I need to modify all the elements that start with INSERT ALL bmw and INSERT ALL ferrari.

In this case, only the first record would be updated, since the second begins with INSERT ALL audi

Comment: None of these strings start with 'AA'....

Comment: @mykaf I made a mistake when writing, it is already updated, thanks

Comment: remember that methods like `.map()`,`.filter()`,`.reduce()` they don't modify your original array, they create a new array for you so you need to save your results in a variable

Comment: @ChrisG True, that is what I did at the beginning, create a new array but it is only created with the modified lines, how can I modify the original then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain all items, including those that do not change, you may not need to use `Array#filter` but `Array#map` and `if` as below:

```js
const 
      arrSt = [ 'INSERT ALL bmw model 320d (111, bmw)', 'ford focus st d (222, ford)', 'INSERT ALL audi a5 rs (333, audi)', 'opel astra d (444, opel)' ],
      
      newArr = arrSt.map(
        item =>
          item.startsWith('INSERT ALL') ?      //check if the item starts with 'INSERT ALL'
          item.replace(/\(\d+,/g, '(NULL,') :  //change it if it does
          item                                 //leave it unchanged if it does not
      );
      
console.log( newArr );
```

Comment: This works. I've never used .map like this, I'm doing tests. One question, is it possible to add multiple values to startsWith()?, that is, modify, for example, those that start with 'INSERT ALL bmw and INSERT ALL fiat'? How can I filter these two within the same startsWith()

Comment: You could use a send `startsWith()` and depending on your needs use **OR** (||) or **AND** (&&) to extend the test/condition. It all depends on the change you want to perform. If the actions you want to perform (change) is different you may to use a nested `if` .. `cond1 ? change1 :  cond2 ? change2 : item`.

Comment: That is what I have tried, but if the number of elements is growing, this is not worth it, because I cannot be entering a conditional per element, I have updated the question, I don't know if it is understood, what I want is to concatenate INSERT ALL with each one of the elements of the array and then startswith of the concatenation

Comment: In the update section of your question you may have to provide an example to clarify your intent.